# Proper use of "replete"

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Is *replete* used appropriately in the following sentence?

> His office was like a Hollywood museum, ***replete*** with an autographed photo of Marilyn Monroe.

Or should *replete* only be used with categorical plurals, such as:

> His office was like a Hollywood museum, ***replete*** *with autographed photos of famous stars*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a room is *replete* with something, then it's full or abundantly supplied with it. If there's only one thing -- in this case, a picture of Marilyn Monroe -- then the room can't be *replete* with it.

Answer (score 8):

I'll just add to the other answers that the first sentence would be much better off with the other "plete" word, **complete**.

Comment: can we use replete and full interchangeably?

Comment: @JayDangar *replete with* and *full of* would be fairly similar, although I wouldn't say they are completely synonymous.

Comment: so are sentences, "Tank is full of water" and "Tank is full with water", same??

Comment: "The tank is full of water" is the normal way to express that.   You could also say "The tank has been filled with water".

Answer (score 4):

Given that *replete* means gorged, plentiful, stuffed.  From the Latin *repleo*, meaning *"to fill up"*.

I doubt a place can be *replete* with a single autograph.

However, I have seen it used in worse context.

Answer (score 3):

The more correct sentence is the second one.
The first sentence you wrote could be understood as describing a very small office, so small that a photograph would fill it.

You can use *replete* with a singular noun, as in

> Sensational popular fiction, replete with adultery.

Comment: That still implies plenty of it. I don't see how you can have plenty of one photo.

Comment: The OP didn't report he was trying to avoid a word that would imply "plenty of it."

Comment: It can be used - wrongly I think - to mean something that is so significant that it takes over the place. If the photo was exceptionally significant, it could be used in this form and be understood.